# Hosting a rails server on a virtual machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-machine, virtualbox, host

I am currently hosing a Debian virtual machine on my Mac OS in which I've installed Ruby 2.4.0. I'm using **Virtualbox and Vagrant**

First of all, **I can't launch my server this way** `rails server` because when I try to access it on my Mac OS web browser, I have this error:

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost didn’t send any data.
```

So, I have to launch it this way : `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` but **I wonder why I can't launch it on 127.0.0.1** (default IP)

Moreover, here's the message I've got when I'm launching my Rails server.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-

5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

While I know that the deprecated stuff warnings are related to the fact that I'm using the newest version of Ruby, I don't understand the last 5 lines :

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.7.1 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Snowy Sagebrush
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Could you explain me the meaning of these?

Last but not least, when I go to http://0.0.0.0:3000, even if I have the correct display (Yay! You're on rails!) I have this strange message on the console.

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-02-25 23:42:38 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"internal"=>true}
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 4.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Could you explain me how to resolve this issue : `Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application running on `localhost` interface on any computer is accessible to other applications running on same computer. In your case, MacOS(host) and Vagrant(guest) box are two different machines. So, one cannot access the applications binding to `localhost` interface on Vagrant box from host machine.

When you run your rails app with `rails s`, rails will bind to interface `localhost` as shown below

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ netstat -an |grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The rails application is accessible to other applications running within the Vagrant box.

On the other hand, if you run your rails application with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, rails app will bind to all the interfaces as shown below.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ netstat -an |grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Running rails app with `-b 0.0.0.0` opens up access to your application from host computer.

But, one needs to do little more before being able to access the rails application. It seems you have already have entries in your Vagrantfile. But, I am adding it here anyway.

Forward the required ports as shown below in Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3001, host: 8001
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3002, host: 8002
end
```

One can use `http://localhost:8000` to reach the rails application running on port 3000 of Vagrant box.

One can disable the `Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255` messages by adding this line in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '10.0.2.2'
```